# Capturar con JAVASCRIPT <img src="..base64"> sin Id, name o value

Tags: javascript

necesito de vuestra ayuda, hace días estoy buscando en internet, tutos y demases como capturaren "JAVASCRIPT" (Exclúyase JQuery) el contenido de un tag img que contiene como src un captcha en formato base64, pero **no tiene Id, name o value al cual hacer referencia** a través de un document.getElement..., si alguien me puede ayudar con algún truquillo, quedaré infinitmente agradecida, dejo el código de lo que tengo hasta ahora, mil gracias...

PD: Solo me sirve para javascript porque va insertado en tampermonkey...

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Página de Prueba</title>
</head>

<body>

<form name="FormIngresa" method="post" action="/ingresa/IngresaAfiliado.do">
 
    <div class="formulario-grupo">
        <label for="tarjeta">Nombre Afiliado</label>
        <input type="text" name="afiliado" value=""  id="afiliado"> 
    </div>
                                

    <div class="formulario-grupo">
        <label for="clave">Clave</label>
        <input type="password" name="clave"  value="" id="clave"> 
    </div>


    <div class="grupo">
    <div class="input">
        <label for="captchaSolve">Digite el siguiente Captcha</label>
        <input type="text" name="captchaSolve" id="captchaSolve">
    </div>

        // El contenido del src es lo que necesito Capturar y asignar a una variable nueva...

        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">                   
     


    <div class="formulario-grupo">
  <button type="button" name="enviar" onclick="javascript:submit">Consultar</button>
    </div>

</form>

// He intentado lo siguiente:


<script>
    var obtieneTagBase64 = document.documentElementByTagName('img').src;
    alert(obtieneTagBase64);
</script>

// También intenté:

<script>
    function creaIdImg(){

        document.documentElement.innerHTML.replace(/<img /g,"<img id='imgBase64'");
            
    }
    creaIdImg();
    
    
    function capturaBase64(){
         var cBase64 = document.getElementById('imgBase64').src;
        alert("el texto es : " + cBase64);
    capturaBase64();   
       
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow. Este comentario es confuso: *El contenido del src es lo que necesito Capturar y asignar a una variable nueva...*  ¿Puedes explicar en el cuerpo de la pregunta, no en un comentario dentro del código, qué es exactamente lo que quieres hacer? Gracias.

Comment: Mil Gracias Albertoooo !!!!.... era justo lo que necesitaba, sos grande....

Comment: Que bueno, si te sirvió recuerda marcar como correcta (Con la palomita a lado de mi post) y esto ayude en futuras consultas como la tuya.

Answer (score 1):

utiliza `querySelector` para retornar el primer selector img. A este ya le podrás sacar su atributo src con `getAttribute`. Aquí tendremos un grave problema si tienes más de una imagen antes del captcha, puesto que `querySelector` retorna el primer nodo. Puedes traer todo un arreglo con `querySelectorAll` y ciclarlo, pero encontrarás dificultades para saber cual es cual. Ahí tendrás que aplicar quizá técnicas de RegEx. Por lo pronto considero esto te puede ayudar con el problema principal

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',function(){
  let base64 = document.querySelector('img').getAttribute('src');
  alert( base64 );
});
```

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
<br>
<button id="btn">Capturar src</button>
```